# Finding out generalize method to get site name from it's website using Jquery

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm trying to get any site's name(just a domain name without any sub domain name) to use in my chrome extension using JQuery. I'm able to find it in most of the cases. but i'm failing in few corner cases.  Here is what i have done till now.

```
host_url = window.location.hostname;
```

This gives me only host name stripping page url, slug or params

```
   https://ap2.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage ->
   ap2.salesforce.com

   http://go.sap.com/support.html -> go.sap.com

   http://www.beaf.com/ -> beaf.com

http://www.digitalclicks.co.uk -> digitalclicks.co.uk
```

but how can I get to only domain name, because to remove sub-domain i can get split it and get the 2nd element which will give me `salesforce, sap, beaf`

```
if (full_domain.split(".").length > 2){
    domain_name =  full_domain.split(".")[1]; // handle the subdomain ie. http://go.sap.com
  }else{
    domain_name =  full_domain.split(".")[0]; //for no subdomain www.beaf.com
  }
```

But I'm failing for `digitalclicks.co.uk`,because here domain name is first. I have to find a generalize approach to solve this. 
And how can I do this for all Top Level Domains??

Comment: Looks like you're misunderstanding what a "top level domain" is - it's only the right-most part - in your examples it is "com" and "uk", with "co.uk" being a Second-level domain.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: as far as the url is concerned the **uk** / **com** in your examples is the top level, the **beaf** / **sap** / **salesforce** / **co** is the 2nd level. So the **digitalclicks** in your case is actually a subdomain. It is just that some 2nd level domains are reserved for/per country specific usages.

Comment: You can get that by removing the top level domain / url extension from the host_url.. ( remove .com, .co.uk etc). Now the last part of the string (splitted by '.') will be the string which you want

Comment: Are these going to be only `.com` and `.co.uk` sites? If they are, use this RegEx: `(\w+)(?=\.co\.uk|\.com)`

Comment: Thanks for the info @freedomn-m , No @Druzion, i have to make it work for all the sites(most of) on the web. and there can be multiple combinatin of first and second level domain, so I have to make two cases work. 1) if now second leve domain then just split and get end element same as `go.sap.com` 2) if there is second level domain then user first element after split. So  it should work for co.uk, co.in, co.en or any other combination if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract domain name from any url.
`http://www.`**domain-name**`.co.uk/sub1/sub2/...`

**This is how it works:**

1. step: it gets rid of `http(s)://`
2. step: it gets rid of everything behind `"/"`
3. creats an array splitted by `"."`
4. cuts the length of the array to 3 to get rid of "**uk**" in "**.co.uk**" f.e.
5. reverse the `array` because the domainname has to be `[1]` then. 
    You have to do this, because the url could be like **domainname.com**
   (without subdomain)

**edit:**
In line 1 we need to add this `+ "/"` in case there is no slash in the url.
But we need a slash in the next step to get the substring.

```js
function getDomainName(url) {
  var _x = url.replace(/\w+:\s?\/\//.exec(url), "") + "/";
  var __x = _x.substring(0, _x.indexOf("/"));
  var __xRev = __x.split(".");
  if (__xRev.length > 3) {
    __xRev.pop();
  }
  __xRev.reverse();
  return __xRev[1];  // <-- __xRev[1] is the domainname
}

document.write(getDomainName(prompt("please enter url")));
```

Comment: I have been able to get the results 
`ap2.salesforce.com
go.sap.com
beaf.com
digitalclicks.co.uk`

but I only want sap, digitalclicks, beaf, salseforce progmatically(if that is a word).

Comment: Thanks @John, let me do a quick check.

Comment: @AkashShah Now this should work for any cases I think.

Comment: Hey, Thanks @John, This is great. The previous one was bit dependent on the input we provide. This looks promising  and have passed all the top 8 URL combinations I have entered. Great work!! Will be accept the answer once I do quick testing with other combinations I have. Thanks a ton buddy!!

Comment: Hey @John, Just integrated code in my app and did some testing.It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton, Props for the explanation. Regex is the way to go.